# footnote with letters instead of numbers

Tags: beamer

I am writing a beamer and the footnote is with letters instead of numbers, how do I change it?

```
The propensity probability is taken from John Palmer et al (2017)\footnote{John Palmer et al {\em Citizen  science  provides  a  reliable  and  scalable  tool  to  track  disease-carrying  mosquitoes.} Nature Communications (2017)}, $p_i(R|e)$:\\
```

but the beamer is with letters instead of numbers:
[image: How it looks the compile pdf]

Comment: Try with `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` somewhere in your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really give enough information to be able to properly identify the issue here. No beamer theme, as far as I can tell, uses letters for footnote numbers, so I'm guessing that what might be happening here is that in your document you're using a `minipage` around the illustration and text which will cause this to happen (some beamer themes may do this behind the scenes, although I don't want to dig too deep into them to figure out which—it would have been far better for you to give us more context about your document). If that's the case, there are two possibilities:

1. Get rid of the `minipage`. You probably don't need it.
2. Do `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` to have footnotes in a minipage numbered instead of lettered. Note, however, that if you have footnotes both inside and outside of the minipage, they'll follow different numbering rules so you *will* see duplicated footnote numbers (and footnote texts in different places).